# Deleting in hibernate with multiple relations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My Entities:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UC> owned = new ArrayList<UC>();
}

@Entity
public class UC{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ukId")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catId")
    private Cat cat;
}

@Entity
public class Cat{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "catId")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UC> owned = new ArrayList<UC>();
}
```

So here is my problem, actually few of them.

Problem #1:

I delete a Cat object, I've set cascadeType.All on the owned list in Cat so when I delete the Cat object all records with Cat in UC will be deleted, however I get "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade" and that is because I have another relation in UC to User where he stores UC in a list. I do not want to delete User object when I delete Cat object and records from UC so setting cascade on @ManyToOne in UC is a no-no. How should I go about it? Before deleting Cat should I remove all instances of UC from User owned list? I have more relations in UC than shown here if that was the case I would have to delete instances from other lists too.

Problem #2:

Similar situation but I got regular Many-To-Many relationship I want to delete the join table record without deleting the other side of relationship.

Comment: not sure that I completely get the point: do you want to delete a Cat entity and automatically remove all references to this cat inside UC table?

Comment: Yes, but without deleting User or other entities in relation. When I don't use cascade inside the UC i get an error when I do User is deleted. I just want to delete Cat, UC records with Cat in it and update the User list of cats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.
First of all, I'll go to set an orphan removal on the OneToMany association, in this way.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Then, suppose you have an User u and a Cat c that you want to remove. This code should work well

```
    // Remove a cat and update the other entities
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.delete(c);
    for (UC uc : c.getOwned())
        uc.getUser().getOwned().remove(uc);
    s.update(u);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
```

Comment: So I delete all occurences of UC from User, but as I say I've got more relations with UC, meaning I have to do it to every other Collection. Is that the correct way of doing that?

Comment: well, if you don't want to do this by code, you can always force an hit to the database to retrieve again the user (with the collections updated). Eg you can invoke `s.delete(c)`,close the session, open new session and invoke `u = s.get(User.class, u.getId())`. Point is that, when you invoke `s.delete(c)`, it actually delete all the references in the UC table (i.e. on the database); however, the local collections (i.e. the owned list) will not be automatically updated. So, if you don't want to update it manually, you have to hit again the database (but I don't think it's a better solution tbh)

Comment: @JohnSmith also, from the answer code, you can do the work acting only on the entity to be deleted (ie the cat c) and get from its collection (ie the owned list uc) the references to the entities that should not be deleted (ie the user u).